# How to avoid unnecessary re-render in other child when I only make change in specific child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my react project

I have three components

One is called BigForm
The other two are called Form A and Form B.

In BigForm, there are two state, DataA and DataB, which would be passed into FormA and FormB.

Question:
Whenever I add input value into Form A or Form B, it will also trigger unnecessary render on the other components.

How can I avoid it? Example code would be appreciated. (please also see my edit before trying) thanks ; I heard redux may help, but I am not sure how to put this in work in this example

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const FormA = (props) => {

  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form A was just rendered')})
  const { dataA, setDataA } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataA(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form A{dataA}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormB = (props) => {
  const { dataB, setDataB } = props;
  useEffect(()=>{ console.log('Form B was just rendered')})
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setDataB(e.target.value)}></input>
      <p>Input Form B{dataB}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export function BigForm (props) {

  const [dataA,setDataA] = useState()
  const [dataB,setDataB] = useState()
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <FormA dataA={dataA} setDataA={setDataA}></FormA>

     <FormB dataB={dataB} setDataB={setDataB}></FormB>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit:

For some reason, it is my intention to set the state in parent, instead of having the child to held its own state, because at the end, I need to aggregate the data from all other forms for other purpose.

.Memo is not what I want too coz in my real examples, it is not working due to there is other complexity preventing it to work.

Comment: When child changes the state of parent, parent will re-render and this causes the other child to re-render. One solution maybe to use redux with a memoized selector library that prevents re-render if the state has not changed.

Comment: Thanks man, May I ask , if you may provide example code? I would upvote and accept it, if it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to optimize re-rendering in React. The first way is shouldComponentUpdate(). This is a function that is called by React before a component is re-rendered. If shouldComponentUpdate() returns false, then the component will not be re-rendered.

The second way to optimize React components is to use PureComponent. PureComponent is a React component that is similar to Component, but it implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow comparison of props and state. This means that if two values are ===, then PureComponent will not re-render the component.

The third way to optimize React components is to use React. memo(). React.memo() is a higher order component that allows you to memoize the result of a component so that it doesn't have to be re-rendered unless the props or state change.

Comment: Thanks man, but this is not quite related to my concern of the problem. please check my edit and the problem.